# Processing 1 million text files with file size between kbs to 100 GB

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to process large number of files starting with a top directory path and apply a transformation (think as converting char a to char b) on each file in the
directory and any files in any sub directories. If top directory path is "/path/to/directory", then the output results will be written to a directory at path "/path/to/directory-converted".
The depth of directories and number of files can be arbitrarily large, 1,000 levels deep and 1,000,000 files. Each input file can be arbitrarily large, e.g. 100GB in size.

I started with writing a recursive function which starts at the top directory, and creates a new file using  new java.io.File(pathToDirectory), checks if a file is a file or directory and does the transformation.

```java
private void applyTransform(File parentFile) {
    for (File fileEntry : parentFile.listFiles()) {
      if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
        applyTransform(fileEntry);
      } else {
        //transform the file
      }
    }
  }
```

Since the recursive method can result in stack overflow, I changed it to use a queue and get a list of files to be processed.

```
public List<String> getAllFilesToTransform(String pathToDir) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    queue.add(pathToDir);

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
      String currentPath = queue.poll();
      File currentFile = new File(currentPath);
      for (File file : currentFile.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
          queue.add(currentPath + "/" + file.getName());
        } else {
          result.add(currentPath + "/" + file.getName());
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now that I have the list of files to process, I can start processing each file. Since each file can be up to 100 GB, I started reading each file and applying the transformation to the characters in the file.

```
private void processFile(String filePath) {
    try {
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(filePath));
      char[] chars = new char[4096];
      while (bufferedReader.read(chars) != -1) {
        transformChars(chars, filePath);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(pathToDir));
      writer.write(fileText);
      writer.close();
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
  }

private void transformChars(char[] chars, String filePath) {
  try {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(pathToDir, true));
      //transform char array and append to file
      writer.write(fileText);
      writer.close();
}
```

I am new to multithreading and the underlying effects of using it.
There are two problems that I want to solve but unsure or have experience of what is the best way and approach to do it.

1. I have to process 10 million files
2. Each of the file can be 100 GB.

To handle the first problem, do I iterate over each file in the list from `getAllFilesToTransform` in a separate class which implements the Runnable interface?
To handle the second problem, can I just read x characters in separate worker threads and run the transform on them and keep writing to the target file?

What is the best way to handle both the problems?

Update - This is not an actual requirement that I am trying to implement at work, but as a mock where I am learning to handle scaling issues and solving them using multi-threading.

Comment: What's your motivation for using Java here? It's my go-to for Web applications, but this seems like something where a shell script+Ruby might be a more straightforward (and easily parallelizable) solution.

Comment: This sounds like a massive project, and if you really have to deal with potentially millions of 100 GB files, then the answer is that a single machine is not reasonable. I would look into a framework like Hadoop, spark,... Something that enables you to have multiple machines do that work in parallel. And of course, the real question that drives your design: what kind of storage infrastructure holds all these files?!

Comment: And note: don't go with empty catch blocks! When doing what you want to do, it is absolutely crucial to exactly understand what happens at runtime. Ignoring exceptions is the exact opposite of good practice!

Comment: if 1000000 files all have 100 Gigabytes each then you are talking about 100 Exabytes of data and 7000 to 8000 of the largest drives on the market.  uploading this much data to the cloud using a 10 gigabit/sec link will take over 2.5 *years*.  so what is the real total?

Comment: @chrylis I am preparing for an interview where they would like to have some knowledge on multi-threading and solving scaling issues as these using Java. This would not be an actual implementation but I wanted to try something hands on and get a better understanding. I am going to update the question to reflect this. Thank you for suggesting using Ruby and shell script as an alternative. I will read up and check the possible options with this approach.

Comment: @GhostCat Thank you for suggesting the approach. I think using Hadoop and Spark would be a good way to go with such a requirement. I will definitely make a project out of this and try at a smaller scale and run it in parallel on an infrastructure like AWS and run it on like an instance which is t2.large (4Gb ram and 2 CPU) instance size on let's say 5 different instances and calculate the processing time. (This is just a starting spec I am thinking of. I will update what I actually used and tried). Thanks!

Comment: @Skaperen I realize the requirement looks vague and impractical when I read through it again. I am updating the scenario - let's say there are just ten 100 gb files out of a million. The rest of the files vary from 500 kb to 10 mb. So the real total would be 1TB (10 mb * 1000000) + 1TB (100 gb * 10) = 2 TB.

Answer (score 5):

For the number of files: Assuming you stay within the monolith design (i.e. one process):

1. Implement a [FileVisitor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html) which inserts files into a blocking queue.
2. Use [walkFileTree()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-) with that file visitor.
3. Use that queue to build a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

For the size of files - if you don't know which files are 100GB and which are 1k (i.e. it's random as far as you're concerned), then just have one task work on one input file and one output file. Buffered streams are optimized for large files, and the system won't keep 100GB in memory.

Comment: Great suggestion. I am going to understand the javadoc for listed in the steps and try this out. Thank you!